# Occasionally, Django messages are repeated across requests (i.e., they are not cleared)

Tags: python, django, oracle

Very rarely, a [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) message is rendered in an `HTML` response. Then, the user `GET`s another page, and the Django message is rendered again. Sometimes, the user will `GET` another page thereafter, and the same message will display once again.

This happens very rarely, but when it does, most users see the same behavior for a few moments. (It happened once in a group cross-browser test, and everyone in the room saw the same behavior on each of their computers for about five minutes before going away.)

This behavior has occurred with many different views; and besides, each view adds them in the same way (see below).

I've been unable to reliably reproduce the error, either in our deployed environment (running `wsgi.py`) or when running the project on a local environment (running `manage.py`). (I will note that I've never seen this problem locally.)

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

*Example of a success message being added.*

```
       messages.success(
            request,
            "Changes to {form} {request} were successfully saved."\
            .format(form=self.form.display_name,
                    request=serv_request_id_as_url(self.serv_request))
        )
```

*This is the template code which renders the message:*

```
<div id="messages">
  {% for message in messages %}
    <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
      <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#" title="Close"><span class="accessibility">Close this message.</span>&times;</a>
      <strong>{{ message.message|safe }}</strong>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

*Relevant settings:*

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'outage.middleware.OutageMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.transaction.TransactionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'utdirect.middleware.HttpHeaderMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', ... )

MESSAGE_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.messages.storage.session.SessionStorage'

DATABASES = {'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
                         ...}}
```

Comment: Can you specify what the message is?

Comment: Just a guess, but if it's only happens in deployed environment it might have something to do with caching or similar... When the problem occurs the server might have spawned new processes that affects the cache, just a thought...

Comment: Please make sure the session read is not cached and that session write actually succeeds. Django will silently ignore sessions that contain unserializable objects for example which could cause the messages to not be removed properly.

Comment: What is your session settings?

Comment: I had the same goddamn problem myself, and could not find any decent solution to it. I ended up just dropping the messages app completely and created my own success and fail notifications

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say you're using a custom write-through cache session backend, no? If so, that's likely the culprit.

Comment: You're most likely using some form of session based message handler which is messing it up. We had the same problem and it went away as soon as we cleared the "message queue" after we had displayed a message.

Comment: I have notice that this thing happens when the browser doesn't clean the cookie with the messages. I don't know why it happens. I don't have cache configuration on my deployment app (yet)

Comment: Against Heisenbugs you will have to read the logs and add more logging to anything that can be related. Have your users report accurately the time at which such problem happened so you know where to look. What I have in mind is maybe duplicate POSTs, either because users double-click on the submit button, or because something else like a proxy on the network is repeating the request ; you may want to look at your existing access_log around the time it was reported. You should then think about what kind of logging you need to prove or invalidate a potential source of this bug.

Comment: A huge hint is that this cached message behavior is repeated across **multiple browsers / computers** for a period of time, on **multiple pages**.

Comment: Is it about the parallel request talked about in here:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/messages/#behavior-of-parallel-requests

Answer (score 2):

It seems this a noted problem caused by caching in Django. Here is the comment made by one Django core developer:

**"I don't think Django can handle this problem automatically and correctly.
It is a very common pattern to loop over messages in the base template of a website. If we disable caching simply because messages might be displayed on a given page, we're just killing the cache for most websites."**

The full ticket is here: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13894